# Using a SDL window with OpenGL the other way around

Tags: opengl, window, sdl

I just recently changed all rendering in my application/game from SDL to OpenGL. I still use SDL for keyboard input, loading images and creating the window.

But since i only render in OpenGL do you think that i should change the window to a OpenGL initialized window instead of a SDL window. The header i use for OpenGL functions at the moment is "SDL_opengl.h". Does that affect things?

What are the advantages and disadvantages if i do this? Right now it feels like it's the logical "next step" since i got rid of all other SDL rendering code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep on using SDL for input and window management.

There's no provision for either in the OpenGL spec so there's really no such thing as an "OpenGL initialized window".

Comment: Thanks. During start-up i sometimes experience that a window named SDL_APP pops up right before the main window does. Why is that?

Comment: You using SDL 1.2 or 1.3/2.0?

Comment: Pretty sure i'm using 1.2. Where do i find info like that, just to be sure?

Comment: I found out, i got version 1.2.17

Comment: Give [`SDL_WM_SetCaption()`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_WM_SetCaption) a try.

Answer (score 0):

As genpfault said, you should keep using SDL for your window initialization.  It's more clean and portable than OS-specific methods of initializing a window for OpenGL rendering.

I would also recommend switching from SDL_opengl.h to SDL.h and gl.h; the definitions in SDL_opengl.h aren't necessary for basic window management, and they conflict with the definitions in other OpenGL libraries like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) (which you may want to use later for pixel shaders and framebuffers).

Comment: Actually with GLEW you can forgo `gl.h` entirely.